# Regex loop parsing with negative word lookahead

Tags: regex, parsing, regex-negation

I am trying to parse the following string, but I can't seem to figure out how to use regex negation on words. I have the following text message history.

```
string = '2014-03-29 10:29:24 AM: John Doe: Hey dude how are you feeling 2014-03-29 10:30:39 AM: Billy: Hey Doe, Im feeling better now. 2014-03-29 10:30:58 AM: Billy: Yup'
```

My regex ruby query currently looks like this:

```
string.scan(/((\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s+[AP][M])\:\s(.*?)\:\s([^\d{4}]*))/) {|match| puts match}

Output:
   2014-03-29 10:29:24 AM: John Doe: Hey dude how are you feeling 
   2014-03-29 10:29:24 AM
   John Doe
   Hey dude how are you feeling 
   2014-03-29 10:30:39 AM: Billy: Hey Doe, Im feeling better now. 
   2014-03-29 10:30:39 AM
   Hason
   Hey Doe, Im feeling better now. 
   2014-03-29 10:30:58 AM: Billy: Yup
   2014-03-29 10:30:58 AM
   Billy
   Yup
```

**Problem**

My Regex negation is only for characters and not the words. **[^\d{4}]** only stops when it detects any number and not the word like '2014'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below one. I have used `?:` to avoid few of the group capturing from your regex. Also, added a positive lookahead `(?=\d{4}-|$)` to see whether there is any `\d\d\d\d-` format is available at next or its the end of line. You can change this into your pattern if you want(i mean make it into `yyyy-mm-dd` format).

```
string.scan(/((?:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s+[AP][M])\:\s(?:.*?)\:.*?)(?=\d{4}-|$)/) {|match| puts match}
```

Output:

```
2014-03-29 10:29:24 AM: John Doe: Hey dude how are you feeling 
2014-03-29 10:30:39 AM: Billy: Hey Doe, Im feeling better now. 
2014-03-29 10:30:58 AM: Billy: Yup
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match all until a specific "word" like this, example with the word "2014":

```
(?>[^2]+|2(?!014))*
```

The same with an unknow year (four digits):

```
(?>[^0-9]+|[0-9](?![0-9]{3}-))*
```

An other way is to split the string with a lookahead:

```
string.split(/(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+[AP][M]:)/)
```

Note: for these three patterns, you can choose how you want to be specific with the length and the precision of the subpattern inside the lookahead assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Character classes don't work like this.

`[^\d{4}]*`

Meaning:

```
^    -  Negative class, so -
\d   -  Not digit 0-9
{    -  Not '{'
4    -  Not '4'
}    -  Not '}'
```

And, the class optionally matches this set many times.
Therefore, it stops, and won't match a number `Not digit 0-9`

Match until a 4 digit word could also be like this

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      (                             # (2 start)
           \d{4} - \d{2} - \d{2} 
           \s+ 
           \d{2} \: \d{2} \: \d{2} 
           \s+ 
           [AP] [M] 
      )                             # (2 end)
      \: \s 
      ( .*? )                       # (3)
      \: \s 
      (                             # (4 start)
           (?:
                (?! \d{4} )              # Not 4 digits ahead of this character
                .                        # Ok, match the character
           )*
      )                             # (4 end)
 )                             # (1 end)
```